# Why $\int{\frac{dr}{r\sqrt{c^{2}r^4 -1}}} = -\frac{1}{2} \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{cr^2}\right)$?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I must solve the following integral, where $c$ is a constant $$\int{\frac{dr}{r\sqrt{c^{2}r^4 -1}}}$$ When I compute and do the calculations, I obtain that $$\int{\frac{dr}{r\sqrt{c^{2}r^4 -1}}} = \frac{1}{2} \arctan \left(\sqrt{c^{2}r^4 -1} \right)$$ I have rectified my calculations many times and I always get the same result, but in the book I'm studying I have that $$\int{\frac{dr}{r\sqrt{c^{2}r^4 -1}}} = -\frac{1}{2} \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{cr^2}\right)$$  Why? Is it some mistake in the book or is it my own mistake? The book I mention is: The calculus of variations by Van Brunt page 47, there the equation arises through an example on the invariance of the Eule-Lagrange equation.

**Attached images:**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This may help:  Let $sin(x)=\frac{1}{y}$, then $cos(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{y^2}}}$ so $tan(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact
$$ \tan\bigg(\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{cr^2}\bigg)\bigg)=\frac{\sin\bigg(\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{cr^2}\bigg)\bigg)}{\cos\bigg(\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{cr^2}\bigg)\bigg)}=\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac1{c^2r^4}}}{\frac{1}{cr^2}}=\sqrt{c^2r^4-1}. $$
Since $\frac{1}{cr^2}>0$, $\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{cr^2}\bigg)\in(0,\pi/2)$ and hence
$$ \cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{cr^2}\bigg)\bigg)=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{c^2r^4-1}. $$
Using
$$ \sin^{-1} x+\cos^{-1} x=\frac{\pi}{2} $$
and hence
$$ -\sin^{-1}x=\cos^{-1}x-\frac{\pi}{2}. $$
one has
$$ -\sin^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{cr^2}\bigg)=\cos^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{cr^2}\bigg)-\frac{\pi}{2}=\tan^{-1}\bigg(\sqrt{c^2r^4-1}\bigg)-\frac{\pi}{2}. $$

Comment: There is only one thing I don't understand in your solution. It consists of the last line of your final equation, that is, why do you get that $\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{cr^2}) = \tan^{-1}(\sqrt{c^2 r^4 -1})$? I need an explanation please.

Comment: Taking the inverse tangent, you will get it. See the update.

Comment: $\frac{1}{y}=cos(x)$, so $\frac{\sqrt{y^2-1}}{y}=sin(x)$ and $\sqrt{y^2-1}=tan(x)$..